# NSImageView added with Interface Builder is null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsimageview

I've the following problem:

I've added a NSImageView to my NSWindow. I set the controller of my Window as the file's owner. I can open my window, click on buttons. It works great. But when I try to set an icon to the ImageView, nothing happens because it's null.

What could be the reason it's null? I checked, and it's connected to the IBOutlet.

Thx

Comment: Could you please post your code. when you are setting the icon

Comment: I don't even need that, NSLog(@"icon %@", icon); where icon is my NSImageView return null...

Comment: Check my answer, Are you allocating and init the icon variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, Just connecting to the `IBOutlet` will not allocate the memory for given variable. Since you haven't allocated the memory it shows null.

So, do this first.

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;
```

and then

```
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
```

and then before you set the image you need to `alloc` and `init` the `_imageView`.

like,

```
_imageView = [NSImageView alloc] init];
```

Comment: ok thx, I thought I did not need to alloc it. It's not nil anymore. but with `[icon setImage:[[NSBundle mainBundle] imageForResource:@"External.icns"]];` I still have nothing in my with (i checked, imageForResource: returns not nil)

Comment: That will be considered as different question :) thanks! glad this question solution is with you